# How can I call local functions inside another local function at the return statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I run the class Fraction, Global Name simplify is not defined is the error I get. Though I have simplify function defined in the same class Fraction. The simplify function when run independently runs perfectly. The Fraction class when run without simplify function, returns the answer not simplified as expected. What's the problem when I try to simplify the Fraction after it has been added?

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    #simplify, simplifies the fraction.(2/4 to 1/2)
    #add, adds two fractions and then returns the simplified fraction.
    def __add__ (self, f):
        if (self.b == f.b) :
            return simplify(Fraction(self.a + f.a , f.b))
        else :
            pro = self.b * f.b
            return simplify(Fraction(self.a * f.b + f.a * self.b , pro))
```

Comment: Where did you define `simplify`? If it is a method on the class, use `self.simplify()`.

Comment: Then please include *all* relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up functions and methods.

A function looks like `f(a, b)`. A method looks like `<class instance>.method(a, b)`

Look at this (I used the Python [fractions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module for easy 'simplify'):

```
import fractions

class MyFraction:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def simplify(self):
        rtr=fractions.Fraction(self.a, self.b)
        print('"simplify({}, {})"={}'.format(self.a,self.b, rtr))    
        return rtr

    #simplify, simplifies the fraction.(2/4 to 1/2)
    #add, adds two fractions and then returns the simplified fraction.
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}/{}'.format(self.a, self.b)

    # alternatively, if you want to always print a simplified fraction:
    # def __str__(self):
        # return fractions.Fraction(self.a, self.b).__str__()

    def __add__ (self, f):
        if (self.b == f.b) :
            return MyFraction(self.a + f.a , f.b).simplify()
        else :
            pro = self.b * f.b
            return MyFraction(self.a * f.b + f.a * self.b , pro).simplify()

print(MyFraction(2,4))   
# 2/4
print(MyFraction(1, 2)+MyFraction(20, 30))  
# "simplify(70, 60)"=7/6
# 7/6
```

As a matter of style, you may wish to use 'numerator' instead of 'a' and 'denominator' instead of 'b' in you class. You may wish to name it 'MyFraction' vs the library 'Fraction' so there is no confusion with someone else looking at your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since `simplify` is a local function, you should use the syntax `Class.function`.
Trying to run just simplify, the interpreter will look for a global `simplify` function.

Here is what you should try instead:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

#simplify, simplifies the fraction.(2/4 to 1/2)
#add, adds two fractions and then returns the simplified fraction.
    def __add__ (self, f):
        if (self.b == f.b) :
            return Fraction.simplify(Fraction(self.a + f.a , f.b))
        else :
            pro = self.b * f.b
            return Fraction.simplify(Fraction(self.a * f.b + f.a * self.b , pro))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanx for your help. It worked!! I was trying self.simplify...which never worked. Can you help me print the Fraction when I run `Fraction(2,4)`. The error I get `__main__. Fraction instance at 0xb744deec>`. I have defined `__str__` function. Hence `print Fraction(2,4)` works fine. Thank you.

Comment: You need a `__repr__` method too for that to work. :-)

Comment: Thank you!! I'm new to python actually. What is the actual use of a __main__ function?? Can you explain it in brief?

Comment: A main function is essentially the function that is run when a script is called. A script is called with the parameter "__name__" = "__main__" and then the person who wrote the script usually choses to run the main method when it is called as
    if "__name__" == "__main__":
        main()

It is nothing more than something to help you organize your code and run the main method first. Hope that helps as well.

Comment: If that was helpful, would you mind verifying it as the correct response. Thanks, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Yaa, I guess that was a goo response. It sure did helped me.

Comment: Could you then click the tick on the left of my response and make it green? Thanks. You're the first person I helped. I feel so proud. :D

Comment: @sshashank124, welcome, have a +1 in the meantime :)

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of the method `__add__` below the `class` definition? Thx

Comment: @dawg, Done! Thanks for noticing that.